# Group by returns only one row

Tags: sql, sqlite

Table `articles` contains 2 rows. When I group by `article.id`, my result has only 1 row, though the second article id should be there too:

```
sqlite> select * from articles;
e5c90df1-d525-46f8-9747-ea2939b8011d|||2021-08-06 18:25:00|2021-08-08 05:53:35.115709|
69c7b4d4-8c43-4f97-acdf-b620dbd528dc|||2021-09-17 21:25:00|2021-09-18 08:38:40.919855|

sqlite> select * from comments;

sqlite> SELECT t1.id, COUNT(t2.id) AS comment_count
   ...> FROM articles AS t1
   ...> LEFT JOIN comments AS t2 ON (t2.article_id = t1.id)
   ...> GROUP BY t2.article_id;
69c7b4d4-8c43-4f97-acdf-b620dbd528dc|0

sqlite> SELECT t1.id, COUNT(t2.id) AS comment_count
   ...> FROM articles AS t1
   ...> LEFT JOIN comments AS t2 ON (t2.article_id = t1.id)
   ...> WHERE t1.id = 'e5c90df1-d525-46f8-9747-ea2939b8011d'
   ...> GROUP BY t2.article_id
   ...> ;
e5c90df1-d525-46f8-9747-ea2939b8011d|0
```

Here is the test database:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "articles" (
    "id"    VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("id")
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "comments" (
    "id"    VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    "article_id"    VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("id")
);
INSERT INTO "articles" VALUES ('e5c90df1-d525-46f8-9747-ea2939b8011d');
INSERT INTO "articles" VALUES ('69c7b4d4-8c43-4f97-acdf-b620dbd528dc');
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Are you certain that this behavior is reproducible?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't know what more could I do to ensure that. I see this in a Python script, in Sqlite browser and in command line. I have added to the question the SQL to create the test db.

Comment: Why do you group by t2.article_id and not t1.id?

Comment: Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jsXBmi5YPAhr7KznaowCcq/0

Comment: @forpas Yes, this works, thanks! Now I need to understand why is that so... The is a simplified query from a more complex version where I need to make count of comments per article. So I thought it's more logical to group by `comments.article_id`.

Comment: `t2.article_id` will be `NULL` because there are no comments.

Comment: Because t2.article_id is null since there is no match there is only 1 group. If you selected t2.article_id instead of t1.id you would see that.

Comment: Thanks for explanation! I guess I'll have to think more about this to understand completely.